# How to Clear() controls without causing a memory leak

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

After reading about `Control.Clear();` causing memory leaks (verified at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx)), I was wondering if:

```
while (Controls.Count > 0) Controls[0].Dispose();
```

will be enough, or do I have to iterate recursively through all controls within controls?

Also, is there any reason to do a `Control.Clear();` after that? (as I saw someone saying somewhere)?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code would loop infinitely.

Comment: @svick No. after every `Dispose()` - what was `Controls[1]` becomes `Controls[0]`.

Comment: Technichally no, because dispose does not remove the actual object, just releases its resources, as I said in my answer you have to explicitly remove the reference after calling dispose.

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek “Technichally no” – what do you mean?

Comment: @ispiro He means that calling Dispose doesn't remove the element from the collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The posted snippet is correct.  No Clear() is required, the Control.Dispose() method already removes the control from the Controls collection.  Which is why it works.

The less alarming version of the loop is:

```
 for (int ix = Controls.Count-1; ix >= 0; --ix) Controls[ix].Dispose();
```

No need to iterate through the children of the control and dispose them, that already happens automatically.

Comment: Hehe, downvoted.  Somebody doesn't take much stock in a 198k backing it seems :)

Comment: That probably came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706528/trying-to-replace-controls-clear-to-avoid-memory-leak-doesnt-work-why

Comment: Hmya, it's poorly understood.  That's why you'd want to use the "less alarming version", in spite of the downvote for it.