# C# Forms - Clearing the form from Buttons, PictureBoxes,

Tags: c#, forms, controls

This is the problem:
I add a lot of buttons, pictureboxes, textboxes and other controls like this:

`btnStart = new Button();` bla bla bla text text text...

And I have been adding more. So, I have learned that I can remove them  one by one:

```
Controls.Remove(btnStart);
```

But what I do want to know is, if there is a way to remove all of them at once, not specifying every single one of them when I want to remove them. Basically I want to create new:

```
private void ClrScr() { //Help??? }
```

Which will remove all controls once called from this form (Everything is done in one form).
Can anyone help out? I'm still quite new at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Controls.Clear( )` should do it.

Edit:

As pointed out below - `Controls.Clear( )` can result in memory leaks. Have a look at this answer: [How to Clear() controls without causing a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705234/how-to-clear-controls-without-causing-a-memory-leak)

Comment: Indeed it does, much appreciated.

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin: Please have a look at the comments in WouterHs answer too. You shouldn't miss that!

Comment: I take into consideration all of the answers.  Do not worry :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all childcontrols of your mainform just use `Controls.Clear()`

If you have some fixed controls you do not want to remove, then add the dynamic generated controls to a Panel. Then you can call `mypanel.Controls.Clear()` to only remove those controls.

EDIT: It seems like Controls.Clear causes memory leaks, so you might use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705234/how-to-clear-controls-without-causing-a-memory-leak) from Hans Passant.

Comment: Not sure, but I think it only removes them, but doesn't dispose them. Isn't this a danger concerning memory leaks?

Comment: If you remove the Control objects from the control container, there are no references anymore to those controls (asuming you don't hold references yourself elsewhere). So the Garbage Collector will take care of disposing those objects.

Comment: In most cases yes, but if you have a reference somewhere, you run into trouble fast. The documentation has an explicit warning: `Calling the Clear method does not remove control handles from memory. You must explicitly call the Dispose method to avoid memory leaks.`

Comment: MSDN warns that ControlCollection.Clear() does not remove handles from memory. It does cause a leak.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear.aspx