# Clear ListView Items without a memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using the `Clear()` method on Controls' **Control**s [causes a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706528/trying-to-replace-controls-clear-to-avoid-memory-leak-doesn-t-work-why#comment9377938_7706549)       (unless they're referenced elsewhere and taken care of there). The solution is to [Dispose of those child Controls instead of Clear()ing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7705553/939213).

However, ListViews' Items [are not **Control**s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#familyToggle) and can't be disposed of. Does this mean that there's also no memory leak using the ListView's Items' `Clear()`? If not - how is a memory leak avoided? Is setting them to null enough? (If, that is, it's needed at all)

**EDIT (to clarify the question)**

The problem with Controls' Controls is that an extra "reference" to them is created when they are `Clear()`ed (See the first link above). Since `ListView` *is* a Control, I was wondering if the same happens to its `Items`, or whether, since they are *not* Controls - no such problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to the documentation then `Clear` does not dispose the control handles, which is what you have to do manually. Handles are unmanaged and you can access them through `Control.Handle` which will return the unmanaged handle for the individual control. Calling `Dispose` upon a control will free the unmanaged handle.

This is `Control.Dispose()` reflected.

```
    /// <summary>Releases the unmanaged resources used by the <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.Control" /> and its child controls and optionally releases the managed resources.</summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources. </param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (this.GetState(2097152))
        {
            object @object = this.Properties.GetObject(Control.PropBackBrush);
            if (@object != null)
            {
                IntPtr intPtr = (IntPtr)@object;
                if (intPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SafeNativeMethods.DeleteObject(new HandleRef(this, intPtr));
                }
                this.Properties.SetObject(Control.PropBackBrush, null);
            }
        }
        this.UpdateReflectParent(false);
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.GetState(4096))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (this.GetState(262144))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ClosingWhileCreatingHandle", new object[]
                {
                    "Dispose"
                }));
            }
            this.SetState(4096, true);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            try
            {
                this.DisposeAxControls();
                ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu)this.Properties.GetObject(Control.PropContextMenu);
                if (contextMenu != null)
                {
                    contextMenu.Disposed -= new EventHandler(this.DetachContextMenu);
                }
                this.ResetBindings();
                if (this.IsHandleCreated)
                {
                    this.DestroyHandle();
                }
                if (this.parent != null)
                {
                    this.parent.Controls.Remove(this);
                }
                Control.ControlCollection controlCollection = (Control.ControlCollection)this.Properties.GetObject(Control.PropControlsCollection);
                if (controlCollection != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < controlCollection.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Control control = controlCollection[i];
                        control.parent = null;
                        control.Dispose();
                    }
                    this.Properties.SetObject(Control.PropControlsCollection, null);
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.SetState(4096, false);
                this.SetState(2048, true);
            }
        }
        if (this.window != null)
        {
            this.window.ForceExitMessageLoop();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

As you can see it frees the unmanaged handler. Which is what `Dispose()` is normally used to or to elaborate further why you usually implemented the `IDisposable` interface.

Let's dig further in the `Dispose` and you will notice this part.

```
this.DestroyHandle();
```

It referres to

```
/// <summary>Destroys the handle associated with the control.</summary>
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [UIPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Window = UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows), SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    protected virtual void DestroyHandle()
    {
        if (this.RecreatingHandle && this.threadCallbackList != null)
        {
            lock (this.threadCallbackList)
            {
                if (Control.threadCallbackMessage != 0)
                {
                    NativeMethods.MSG mSG = default(NativeMethods.MSG);
                    if (UnsafeNativeMethods.PeekMessage(ref mSG, new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), Control.threadCallbackMessage, Control.threadCallbackMessage, 0))
                    {
                        this.SetState(32768, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!this.RecreatingHandle && this.threadCallbackList != null)
        {
            lock (this.threadCallbackList)
            {
                Exception exception = new ObjectDisposedException(base.GetType().Name);
                while (this.threadCallbackList.Count > 0)
                {
                    Control.ThreadMethodEntry threadMethodEntry = (Control.ThreadMethodEntry)this.threadCallbackList.Dequeue();
                    threadMethodEntry.exception = exception;
                    threadMethodEntry.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
        if ((64 & (int)((long)UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowLong(new HandleRef(this.window, this.InternalHandle), -20))) != 0)
        {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.DefMDIChildProc(this.InternalHandle, 16, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        else
        {
            this.window.DestroyHandle();
        }
        this.trackMouseEvent = null;
    }
```

`DestroyHandle` is the actual method that destroys the handle of the control, but the control may have more unmanaged handles as you can see in `Dispose` where it first destroys the handle of the `PropBackBrush`.

As you can see `Control` handles unmanaged memory. If the items in your `ListView`  doesn't contain any unmanaged memory then you don't need to worry about it, because the `GC` will take care of it.

If the items contain unmanaged memory then you would have to handle each item individual, preferably make them inherit `IDisposable` and then call `Dispose` upon then manual. You could create an extension method to do it for you if you don't want to loop through the items every time you're clearing your list.

The above is mostly related to a custom `ListView` control, where you render the `ListView` yourself based on objects. The standard `ListViewItem` in .NET does not store unmanaged memory and thus the `GC` takes care of the memory when the `ListView` is clearing the items and/or when it's disposed.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with Controls' Controls are that there's an extra reference to them that is created when they are Clear()-ed (See the first link in my question). Since ListView _is_ a Control, I was wondering if the same happens to its `Items`, or whether, since they are _not_ Controls - no such problem exists.

Comment: I do not believe there's any extra reference to them

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to ownership. If noone else is referencing those items, you will need to Dispose of the items properly.

The way to do it is to remove the items from the list of items, and checking each and every one to see if it implements IDisposable, and then Dispose of it.

```
while (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
    var item = listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count -1);
    listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.Items.Count -1);
    if (item is IDisposable)
    {
        ((IDisposable)item).Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with references to them, considering C# has garbage collection. It has to do with if they have unmanaged resources or not such as handles. Also the question is related to a `ListView` where the items are not of `object`, but of `ListViewItem`